# Ruby on Rails and Best_in_place on client only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I have one table in my Rails application which is uploaded from external file and i have to validate it and solve format errors before saving it on the server.

So i want to use best_in_place for in-grid editing. But as i noticed after each change best_in_place tries to send update to the server. I don't need. I want to solve all errors on client and only then send my data to server.

Is it possible to tell best_in_place to work on client only? If it is not, can u advice me another lib for in-grid table editing on rails?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

best_in_place works like that and yes, you need it.

For example:

1. You changed two rows in your table
2. You click refresh page in your browser

If it worked like you want then your changes disappeared.

Thanks to best_in_place your changes were commited and you can continue your work